# How make a summ of 2 attributes in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to learn more about classes and objects in Python and the following is an example given in a tutorial. In the below code I am using:

```
class Employee(object):
    'common base clase for all employee'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, surname, pay):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.pay = pay
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print('Total employee {}'.format(Employee.empCount))

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print('Name: ', self.name, ', Surname: ', self.surname, ', Pay: ', self.pay)

    def summPay(self):
        pass
```

I have passed to that class 2 objects, `emp1` and `emp2`

```
emp1 = Employee('Federico', 'Olivieri', '5000')
emp2 = Employee('Anonymous', 'Friend', '6500')
```

What I want is to create another method `summPay` under the `Employee` class to make the sum of all salary. I know I could try to use a local variable and increment the variable as for `empCount` but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: You can do it in the constructor itself as and when you create new objects

Comment: Can you give me a code example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Employee(object):
    'common base clase for all employee'
    empCount = 0
    sum = 0

    def __init__(self, name, surname, pay):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.pay = pay
        Employee.empCount += 1
        Employee.sum+=pay

    def displayCount(self):
        print('Total employee {}'.format(Employee.empCount))

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print('Name: ', self.name, ', Surname: ', self.surname, ', Pay: ', self.pay)

    def summPay(self):
        return self.sum

emp1 = Employee('Federico', 'Olivieri', 5000)
emp2 = Employee('Anonymous', 'Friend', 6500)
print(emp2.summPay())
```

Here initialise a variable sum, after creation of each and every object, constructor is called and in the constructor sum is incremented.

After the last object creation, call the function `summPay()`

Comment: actually he already knows how to do that, but he is asking if there is a better way to do it